# How to change fontSize in react icon using styled components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-icons

I want to make hover effect with increase of icon size, icons are from react icons, I'm using styled components. How should I do it ?

```
 export const BottomBar = () => {
  const style = { fontSize: "180%" };
  return (
    <StyledBottomBar>
      <StyledIcon>
        <FaFacebookSquare style={style} />
      </StyledIcon>
      <StyledIcon>
        <GrInstagram style={style} />
      </StyledIcon>
      <StyledIcon>
        <CgMail style={style} />
      </StyledIcon>
      <StyledIcon>
        <BiPhoneCall style={style} />
      </StyledIcon>
    </StyledBottomBar>
  );
};
```

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do inline style's actions like `:hover`. You could use JS approach `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave`:

```
const style = { fontSize: "180%",transition: 'font-size 0.5s'  };
...
<FaFacebookSquare style={style} onMouseEnter={({target})=>target.style.fontSize= "180%"} 
  onMouseLeave={({target})=>target.style.fontSize= "100%"}/>
```

Or you could divide them into Component `<StyledIcon/>` and then `useRef`, `useEffect` and `useState` to do the hover.

```
const style = { fontSize: "180%",transition: 'font-size 0.5s' };
export function StyledIcon(props){
const [hover,setHover] = useState(false)
const iconRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(hover){
      iconRef.current.style.fontSize="200%"
    }
    else{
      iconRef.current.style.fontSize="180%"
    }
  },[hover]) // changing fontSize whenever the hover state is updated
const handleIconType = ()=>{
    switch(props.type){
      case 'facebook':
        {
          return <FaFacebookSquare style={style} ref={iconRef} onMouseEnter={()=>{setHover(true)}} onMouseLeave={()=>{setHover(false)}}/>
        }
      ...// cases for different type of icon
      default:
        return null
    }
  }
  return(
  <>
     <FaFacebookSquare style={style} ref={iconRef} onMouseEnter={()=>{setHover(true)}} onMouseLeave={()=>{setHover(false)}}/>
  </>
  )
}
export const BottomBar = () => {
  
  return (
    <StyledBottomBar>
      <StyledIcon type="facebook">
      </StyledIcon>
      <StyledIcon type="instagram">
      </StyledIcon>
    </StyledBottomBar>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

So react-icons will be rendered as `<svg>` elements. These have properties that you can override with styles, you can only manipulate them with actions on the element itself.

In your example, if you look at the dev-tools and inspect the html, there is probably a div wrapper around the svg element meaning that the styles you tried to apply to them were applied to the div instead.

```
const style = { fontSize: "180%",transition: 'font-size 0.5s'  }

//Try writing it like this:
const style = {
    '& svg': {
        fontSize: '180%',
        transition: 'fontSize 0.5s'
    }
}
```

Here we are applying those rules to the svg element and not its wrapper.

**EDIT**
If you want to listen for clicks or hovers you listen on the div that wraps the svg! Make sure it has the same size, too.